# Deployment of GridGain 6 as a custom module in JBoss 7.1.1-Final

Tags: jboss7.x, gridgain

We have attempted to package and deploy GridGain 6 as a custom static module within our JBoss 7.1.1-Final application server. When run locally, the configuration appears to work and grid jobs are executed by the local node, but when a job is executed on a remote node we get a ClassNotFoundException which appears to indicate that the module code cannot find a class that is contained within the EAR file that is deployed in that instance of JBoss.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.our.company.CustomGridJob from [Module "com.gridgain:main" from local module loader @5e48a0e1 (roots: /path/to/jboss/modules)]
```

From initial debugging it looks like the GridGain module is attempting to un-marshal the serialized message it receives from the network and is looking for the class to construct to initiate the job that it was sent. When the same job is executed locally we assume the serialization/un-marshalling part doesn't happen as there is no network to traverse, so local execution works.

The class it is looking for is present in the EAR deployed to the server so it would appear to be a classloading visibility issue.  Is it possible to make modules 'aware' of code that is deployed to the container? If so, how?

If this approach of deploying GridGain isn't possible are there any other alternatives to simply packing GridGain with our EAR deployment in the /lib directory of the EAR? (Which would really bloat the deployment). How have others deployed GridGain 6 in JBoss 7?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JBoss classloading](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html) documentation, every module can declare dependencies on other modules. I am not sure if static module can declare a dependency on dynamic module (if yes, problem is solved). If not, then you can deploy GridGain as a separate dynamic module, and declare a dependency from GridGain module to your EAR module. The EAR module would have to declare a dependency on the GridGain module (I believe that circular dependencies are supported).

This way all classes declared in the EAR module should be visible to the GridGain module.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I played around with jboss-deployment-structure.xml a bit but couldn't get something working so, pressed for time, I eventually resolved this by placing all the GridGain jars in the EAR/lib - the most straightforward deployment, though not the most efficient. When I get some more time I may re-visit re-packing this another way to reduce the size of the deployed application.